# Identify a movie in which aliens believed a sci-fi TV show to be a true documentary

Tags: story-identification

I remember watching a sci-fi movie in the early 00s. It was full of comedy. Here are the details I recalled:

- There was a space opera TV show in the movie. It seemed a true copy of Star Trek (they used to pilot a ship and there were captain, first officer, science officer etc on the bridge). The name of the TV show was possibly the name of the movie.
- Once the main crew of the TV show were celebrating some achievement, they were approached by humans having weird behaviour (they were aliens in disguise; in reality, they looked like an octopus).
- The alien race was innocent. They couldn't comprehend the concept of art, lies etc. So, they believed that the TV show (they got the EM waves) was a true historical documentary of mankind. So, they came looking for help from the brave captain of the show.
- From the TV show details, they had built a starship which worked. The aliens needed the TV show crew to pilot the ship to defeat another alien race that terrorized them. The TV show crew didn't have any problems piloting the ship as the controls were familiar, only these controls were real.

Can you please identify the movie?

Comment: As a slightly less serious answer, it kind of sounds like an episode of [Futurama](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/When_Aliens_Attack).

Comment: 1) how can this not be a dupe according to the recent meta post on same answers and id questions? 2) seriously? I honestly find it hard to believe a user w/ such high rep on this site is legitimately asking this question - is this Google padding / rep bumping the site or something?

Comment: @NKCampbell What do you mean? Give me meta link. Also, I still don't have correct keywords to get the answer from Google.

Comment: I think this is a case where, despite the answer being the same movie, the questions are not actually duplicates. In particular, the answer to this question does not answer the older question, because it does not mention the rock monsters, and the answer to the old question does not answer this question, because it doesn't address the fiction-believed-to-be-real aspect.

Comment: Alternatively, you could Google "movie where aliens believe star trek is real" and get the answer immediately.

Comment: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10620/aw-shucks-the-frustration-is-strong-in-this-one

Comment: @ovinophile Wow. The TV show wasn't Star Trek, but it still works. An example, when you can articulate what you want to say without infringing trademarks and copyrights.

Comment: @NKCampbell I still don't get it.. Which other question is in conflict here?

Comment: @ovinophile You don't get to hit the rep cap that way, though...

Comment: @NKCampbell If you've found a suitable duplicate target for this question, then by all means vote to close it. But the question you link to is about *Soul Rider* and not *Galaxy Quest*.

Comment: The South Park episode called "Canceled" is about an alien reality tv show where the entire planet of earth is the star of the show.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancelled_(South_Park)

Answer (score 216, accepted):

This is *Galaxy Quest*. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Quest):

> Parodying television series such as Star Trek and its fandom, the film stars Tim Allen, Sigourney Weaver, Alan Rickman, Tony Shalhoub, Sam Rockwell, and Daryl Mitchell as the cast of a defunct television series called Galaxy Quest, in which the crew of a spaceship embarked on intergalactic adventures. Enrico Colantoni stars as the leader of an alien race who ask the actors for help, believing the show's adventures were real.

Comment: And it is a good one :).

Comment: Never surrender, never give up!

Comment: Also, if you have the DVD you can watch the movie in Thermian :D

Comment: Movie? You mean the documentary, of course...

Comment: Please: historical documents

Comment: By Grabthar's hammer, by the Sons of Warvan, you shall be upvoted!

Comment: The best Star Trek movie ever made.

Comment: There's a Galaxy Quest series in the works, btw. Last I heard, Amazon was producing it.

Comment: @WayneWerner I remember that quote backwards.

Comment: @T.E.D.: ...a Galaxy Quest show continuing the movie, or a show reenacting the original historical documents?

Comment: It was supposed to star the original cast. Whether it was meant as following on the plot of the movie, or reenacting the historical documents, still isn't clear; but it's been binned since the death of Alan Rickman. [link](http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/04/07/galaxy-quest-tv-show-on-hold-was-meant-to-star-original-cast)

Comment: @RossPresser - It was listed as a 'sequel' so likely to continue from where the movie left off. It's not entirely 'binned' just put on 'indefinite hold' with Rickman's passing and Tim Allen's current schedule

Comment: "Hold, please".

Comment: Fun note: my college roommate and his girlfriend went to see this at a small theater, and the **film melted** right as Tim Allen hits the Omega Device. It was almost a week before they found out what happened.

Comment: I hate to break it to you Jason, but I don't know how to shut down a neutron reactor, and unless you took a Learning Annex course

Comment: These comments reveal how great the movie is!

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I kind of agree with you, even if semi-officially it's only the [seventh best Star Trek film](http://birthmoviesdeath.com/2013/08/11/the-star-trek-movies-as-ranked-by-star-trek-con-goers) of all time (as of 2013).

Comment: Whoever wrote this episode should die!!!

Comment: No time for pleasantries Kyle, we have a level 5 emergency! (as you can tell by now, it's one of my favourite movies). :)

Comment: Mother, I cannot stress enough to you the severity of Commander Taggart's situation!

Comment: Probably the quote that made me laugh the hardest: "Let's get out of here before one of those things kills Guy!"

Comment: When I saw this in the theatre with my father, the only reason I wasn't rolling in the aisle with laughter is because _dad_ had the aisle seat...

Answer (score -5):

Sounds like 'Galaxy Quest', featuring Tim Allen, Sigourney Weaver et.al. I use this 'The Historical Documents' myself. How would an Alien Species be able to tell fiction from truth? Very interesting points...

Comment: Yes, but this is already covered in the accepted answer (the one with green check mark). On story identification questions, there is no need to post new answers once there is an accepted one - unless you have an exceptionally thorough and well-researched answer, containing previously-uncovered details.